# 144 foot thrown dagger with no feats, can this be true?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I was wondering about how strength applies to throwing and distance and thank Super Kami Guru I ran into this page.

http://sites.legendsmiths.com/pathfinder/pathfinder/rules/throwing

On the table of light objects and distance, a 1 lb. dagger's "Base" thrown distance is the users Strength score times 8. Now before I go Sniper Dagger Happy, there are a few things I hope you folks can clear up.

1) Str 18 x 8 = 144, so a 1 lb. dagger can be thrown 144 feet right?

2) How do range increments factor in, divide total distance by five or multiply total distance by 5?

3) Can you still add you Str mod to the damage should the dagger finds its mark?

4) How does this effect feats as Distance Thrower, Far Shot, Deadly Agility, Two Weapon Fighting, Rapid Shot, etc?

Answer (score 9):

The site linked in the question is to a house/alternate rule. If you are playing in a game which uses that rule, you should confirm your interpretation with the GM. If you are considering using this rule in your own campaign, I would be hesitant. In either case, this GM would suggest limiting those rules to non-weapons (or, to using weapons in other than their intended ways: "I hurl my bow at the enemy, since I'm out of arrows and desperate").

The actual rule from Paizo is:

> With a ranged weapon, you can shoot or throw at any target that is within the weapon’s maximum range and in line of sight. The maximum range for a thrown weapon is five range increments. For projectile weapons, it is 10 range increments. Some ranged weapons have shorter maximum ranges, as specified in their descriptions.

-- [Ranged Attack Increments](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons#TOC-Ranged-Attack-Range-Increments)

A [Dagger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/dagger) has a range increment of 10 feet. Thus, in the official Pathfinder rules, a dagger can be thrown up to 50 feet (albeit at a [-10 penalty](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons#TOC-Range)).

That said, the linked rules would suggest that (18*8=)144 feet is the base; a human could add 15 feet by getting a running start; a [Great Wyrm Red Dragon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/chromatic-red/red-dragon-great-wyrm) would have a base of (43*8)=344 feet, +125 feet when flying (for 469 feet), x16 for being colossal = 7504 feet (a hair over 1.4 miles). That dagger would also do 20d6 damage if the dragon hits (which, to be fair, would require a natural 20 with the -3752 in range increment penalties). That all seems ... excessive.

Comment: One thing maybe worth noting is that core rules weapon ranges are for their effective range **as weapons**; IIRC the rules note it's possible to throw them even farther, but not to hit targets for damage… but the rules don't provide rules for mere throwing-as-transportation. (Since the core rules don't care about throwing thrown weapons beyond their useful range, I can see the house rule being useful for “how far can I physically move this dagger by throwing,  if I, say, wanted to chuck it to my friend across this chasm?”)

Answer (score 4):

As it says on the [SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/dagger), a dagger's base range increment is 10ft, 2nd range increment is 20ft, 3rd is 30ft, and so on as usual.

Throwing weapons use your Strength mod for damage.

All those feats affect daggers that are thrown as normal, and you can throw as many of them in a round as you have daggers and actions to draw them.